# Escape parentheses around a number in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

How do you escape parentheses around numbers in Google Sheets so that they don't default to displaying as negative numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do with the data and if this would mess it up, but you can prefix the number with a `'` (single quote) and it will not display as negative (e.g. `'(3)` will display as `(3)`).

Comment: Cool, happy it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If to preserve the data as a number (for arithmetic operations) the parentheses might be added with formatting, eg the `2` in the image has been formatted with a Custom number format of:

```
(#)
```

[image: WA31758 example]

So the formula in A4 adds the content of A2 as a positive number. However departing from convention in such a way clearly is not a good idea, in general.